# API to update the callbackurl and verify token of the facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an api to updated the callback url and verify token of the webhooks in the messenger settings if we know the Application Id and the Application Secret ?

Comment: did you check out the api docs? i doubt that there is a way though, what is the use case?

Comment: Yes, i did. I was not ale to find one.

Comment: there is your answer then ;)